# I can not build my maven project using java derby and JavaFX. package java.sql is not visible. how can I solve the problem?

Tags: java, maven

I'm tired of looking for a solution to this problem.
Why aren't my libraries imported?

exactly problem is why my library not imported?

i have jdk 15 nad javafx13 and derby 5.0.2.

please help me:)

```
package example.mavenproject2;
    
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a way to solve this problem.

in the maven project, we have a module file.

and to import these classes we have entered some(requires statement) as like this:

module your module file name {

requires java.sql;

requires java.desktop;

}